# How can I convert intent to deep link?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I have sample code as below for Android Java:-

```
public void OpenAppbyName(String appname, String user, String password) {
ComponentName componetName = new ComponentName("com.xxx","com.xxx.yyy.zzz");
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setComponent(componetName);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("data", "user1" + "|" + "abc123"); intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

May I know how can I trigger and access this link in react native?

Example something like this :=

```
com.xxx://com.xxx.yyy.zzz?data=user1|abc123
```

Please help..